# Transpor colunas paras linhas no data frame em Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Boa noite colegas do stack.  Primeiramente quero agradecer pelas ajudas que esse vcs proporcionam.  Venho por favor pedir mais uma ajuda. Conforme a imagem abaixo, gostaria de transpor todos os dados  referente a mesma data numa unica linha. Ex. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que *df* é o seu DataFrame:

```
temp = df.groupby('data').cumcount() + 1

df = df.set_index(['data', temp]).unstack().sort_index(1, level=1) 

df.columns = ['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in df.columns]
```

Comment: Oi Leonardo,  ficou perfeito.  Muito Obrigado.